# Automated Inclusion of Objects in Python List

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary, containers

I'm declaring a class, and in the `__init__` method, I'm declaring two variables which will be associated with an instance of that class. Each declared variable is initialised as a NumPy array of zeros that is later filled with other data.

At some point, outside of this `__init__` method, I need to loop through an object containing each of these variables (NumPy arrays) and reset the array values in each to zero. Thus, in the `__init__` method, I would like to add all of these variables to a list to later iterate through. If I do that once manually, it's trivial.

However, I need to frequently add and remove some number of these variables being declared in `__init__`. Every time I do that, I don't want to have to manually adjust the variables that are contained in the list.

How can I create a `list`, `dict`, or other container of these variables that automatically adjusts itself so it contains all of these variables being initialised, regardless of the number of those variables? As an additional complication, `self.container_of_arrays` must not contain "other" variables from `__init__`, such as `self.array_length`.

What I have, where `self.container_of_arrays` must currently be manually adjusted if a `self.my_variable_three` is created:

```
class generic_class():
    def __init__(self, array_width_one, array_width_two):
    self.array_length = some_integer

    self.my_variable_one = numpy.zeros((self.array_length, array_width_one), dtype=float)
    self.my_variable_two = numpy.zeros((self.array_length, array_width_two), dtype=float)

    self.container_of_arrays = [self.my_variable_one, self.my_variable_two]
```

I tried to declare my variables within a `dict`, so that from the very start they are contained within that `dict`, but this leads to there being references to undefined variables. E.g.

```
    self.container_of_arrays = OrderedDict([(self.my_variable_one, numpy.zeros((self.array_length, array_width_one), dtype=float)),
                                            (self.my_variable_two, numpy.zeros((self.array_length, array_width_two), dtype=float))
                                           ])
```

**Update:**

xli's answer provides the correct solution. As suggested, it's possible to access the arrays by name using a dict or OrderedDict. For anyone who wants to do so, here's the code I've actually implemented:

```
my_data = [('variable_one_name', len(variable_one_data)),
           ('variable_two_name', len(variable_two_data)),
          ] # Intentionally outside the class in a location where variables are added by the user

class generic_class():
    def __init__(self, array_length, my_data):

    self.container_of_arrays = OrderedDict((variable_name, numerix.zeros((array_length, array_width), dtype=float))
                                                    for variable_name, array_width in my_data)
```

Comment: Do you need to reference these arrays by attribute name, e.g. `my_variable_one`, or can you just index in the container, `container_of_arrays[1]`.  Since this is a list, you can easily `append` new items and delete ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a variable for each numpy array, why don't you just create a list of arrays containing each array you need, and reference them by index?

```
class generic_class():
    def __init__(self, array_length, array_widths=[]):
        self.array_length = array_length
        self.arrays = [
             numpy.zeros((self.array_length, array_width), dtype=float) 
             for array_width in array_widths
        ]
```

Then you can access each array by index as `self.arrays[i]`.

Or, if you need to access the array by name, you can use a dict with just a string (the name of the array) as the key for each array.